# Replacing specific word in text with uppercase version of itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

Ok, so this shouldn't be nearly this difficult, but I'm drawing a blank. So, the idea of this program is that it finds words that only occur in a text once, then capitalizes them. Here's the complete code:

```
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

path = input("Path to file: ")
with open(path) as f:
    word_counts = Counter(word.strip(punctuation) for line in f for word in line.replace(")", " ").replace("(", " ")
                      .replace(":", " ").replace("", " ").split())

wordlist = open(path).read().replace("\n", " ").replace(")", " ").replace("(", " ").replace("", " ")

unique = [word for word, count in word_counts.items() if count == 1]

for word in unique:
    text = wordlist
    text.replace(word, str(word.upper()))

print(text)
```

It just prints the regular text, with no modifications made.

I know for a fact the first part works, It's just the final for loop thats giving me trouble.

Any idea what I'm screwing up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line

```
text.replace(word, str(word.upper()))
```

with

```
text = text.replace(word, str(word.upper()))
```

`string.replace()` does not modify the original string instance.

Comment: AHHH. thank you so much I'll accept it as answer as soon as I'm allowed to!

Comment: ok, so one more thing. when the expected output should be `Genesis 37:1 Jacob lived In the land of his father's SOJOURNINGS, in the land of Canaan.`, it prints  `GenesIs 37:1 Jacob lIved In the land of hIs FATher's SOJOURNINGS, In the land of Canaan. ` I believe this is because of the fact that the capitalized letters appear in other keywords. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: Please open a new question for this with a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign it back to text.

```
text = text.replace(word, str(word.upper()))
```